# How to filter date range from multiple columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
dose1 <- c("2022-08-21","2022-09-21","2022-10-21","2022-06-21","2022-09-21","2022-09-21")
dose2 <-c("2022-07-21","2022-09-21","2022-09-21","2022-10-21","2022-09-21","2022-09-21")
dose3 <-  c("2022-02-21","2022-09-21","2022-09-21","2022-08-21","2022-09-21","2022-09-21") 
count_dose1<-  c("50","200","250","50","15","2") 
count_dose2<-  c("10","20","37","10","15","20") 
count_dose3<-  c("90","280","24","79","58","12") 
df<- data.frame(dose1,dose2, dose3, count_dose1,count_dose2,count_dose3)
```

I wanted the data from date 15-09-2022 to 15-10- 2022. I was looking for a way to filter the data based on the date range from all three columns. I was able to do it one column after another by `df%>% filter(dose1 > as.Date('2022-09-15') & dose1  <as.Date('2022-10-15'))` Please let me know if there is any way to create a data frame with the dates that falls in the range from 15-09-2022 to 15-10- 2022.

Comment: you may be looking for `dplyr::between()`

Comment: If possible, I would think about whether this data can be in a tidy "long" format, as opposed to "wide". If you had 3 columns: dose name (dose1, dose2...), dose date and dose count, I think analysis would be much easier.

Comment: Do you want to filter based on whether the date is in the range for **all** 3 columns, or **any** of the 3 columns?

Comment: thank you date must be in range for all 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` with `if_all` and `between` from `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(if_all(dose1:dose3, ~ between(.x, as.Date('2022-09-15'), as.Date('2022-10-15'))))

       dose1      dose2      dose3 count_dose1 count_dose2 count_dose3
1 2022-09-21 2022-09-21 2022-09-21         200          20         280
2 2022-09-21 2022-09-21 2022-09-21          15          15          58
3 2022-09-21 2022-09-21 2022-09-21           2          20          12
```